# How to implement Hibernate Interceptor for different type of CRUD actions and get the class name of the java object which has been modified?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to get the type of object(s) in the PostUpdateEvent,is it possible?
Also is it possible to have one listener for all CRUD events POST commit..like PostUpdateEventListener & PostDeleteEventListener clubbed together?

```
public class PostUpdateDoSomething implements PostUpdateEventListener
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Override
    public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event)
    {


     // How Can I get the class name or Object type here?
    /*This seems to be not working ---------*/

    Class<? extends Object> className = event.getEntity().getClass();
    System.out.println(className);

    /*--------Not Working------------------*/


    }


    @Override
    public boolean requiresPostCommitHanding(EntityPersister event)
    {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/ and https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html

Comment: @StanislavL this example is not suited for my needs. postFlush willl not give me the type i.e UPDATE/DELETE/saveOrUpdate etc. Also the classname problem remains

Answer (score 1):

Usually `getClass` should work. There's the possibility though that the entity is a Hibernate proxy or a subclass of the entity.

To test if it's a proxy you could do something like

```
if (object instanceof HibernateProxy) {
    _clazz = (Class<T>) ((HibernateProxy) object).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation().getClass();
} else {
    _clazz = (Class<T>) object.getClass();
}
```

To test subclasses, you'd need `final Class<?> parent = cls.getSuperclass();`